# com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE is not supported by Google App Engine's Java runtime environment

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Tried to use AES functionality in SunJCE but got an error saying

> com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE is not supported by Google App Engine's
>   Java runtime environment

Anyone familiar with this?

Answer (score 0):

AppEngine's Java runtime environment has a whitelist of all the classes from the JRE that can be used. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist

The code sample in this email thread shows one way of doing AES encryption on AppEngine.  That would be a good place to start.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/YM8axluLtHg